# "Content" or "Contents"?

Tags: grammatical-number, nouns

*Content* or *contents* — when do I use which form?

I realize that the one is the plural form of the other, but they seem to be used interchangeably.

Comment: The question about `“file content” vs. “file contents”` might be useful as well: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56831/file-content-vs-file-contents

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You should be aware where you're using it.

According to [ldoce](http://www.ldoce.com):

- **contents**  [*plural*] : 1) the things that are inside a box, bag, room etc 2) the things that are written in a letter, book etc

> She kept the contents of the letter a secret.

- **content** [*singular*]   the amount of a substance that is contained in something, especially food or drink

> water with a low salt content

- **content** [*singular, **uncountable***]: the ideas, facts, or opinions that are contained in a speech, piece of writing, film, programme etc

> *The content of the media course includes scripting, editing, and camera work.*

- **content** [*singular, **uncountable***]: the information contained in a website, considered separately from the software that makes the website work

> *The graphics are brilliant. It’s just a shame the content is so poor.*

Comment: To summarize: if it's countable, it's plural.

Comment: So what form would I use if I have multiple pieces of content for a book or a web site? Content items? Or just content?

Comment: @Malvolio The contents of a letter is (are?) countable? That sounds wrong. You mean the words? Then I can also count the frames in a movie.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I agree, not to Mention, the amount of a substance is clearly countable, too (in mass, concentration, …).

Answer (score 8):

The *New Oxford American Dictionary* entry for **content** has:

> **1.** (usu. *contents*) the things that are held or included in something: *he unscrewed the top of the flask and drank the contents | he picked up the correspondence and scanned the contents*.
>
> • [usually in singular] the amount of a particular constituent occurring in a substance: *milk with a low-fat content*.
>
> **2.** the substance or material dealt with in a speech, literary work, etc., as distinct from its form or style: *the outward form and precise content of the messages*.

So, it tends to be used in the plural, except in certain particular cases.

Comment: Note that in a book, the "content" usually refers to all the text in the book, but the "contents" (or "table of contents") usually refers to the list of chapters :-)

Comment: So an editor edits content (of a book) irrespective of the number of books they edit?