# "The contents are" or "the contents is"

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number

I have the following sentence:

> The contents of those zip files are normally installed from the Setup.

[I found](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13556/content-or-contents) I have to use *contents* instead of *content* in the sentence.  However, do I have to use *the contents are* or *the contents is*?  I guess it's "are", but it just sounds wrong. (I am a French speaker, and "contenu" is never plural in French, so that might explain why I think "are" is wrong.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you've deduced, you need to use "*are*" since the subject is plural.

> The contents of those zip files are normally installed from the setup.

Comment: Is it still plural when dealing with the contents of a single container? E.g. 'The contents of the bag change after the first draw'.

Answer (score 4):

It's *are* but your example tricked me at first.  I mistakenly thought it was because of *files* and not because of *contents*.

> The contents of the zip file are normally installed from the Setup.

Is also correct.

"of the zip file" is a prepositional phrase in this scenario, which can be removed from the sentence to test the grammar.

> The contents *are* normally installed from the Setup.

Answer (score 0):

Contents is perfectly OK with a singular verb. It is a different word from content. It's effectively shorthand for the Contents page. Thus, the contents is all that matters. It should not be thought of as a plural of content.

Comment: While I certainly feel notional agreement is almost always the best option, I'd argue that 'contents' here is a non-count noun unusually (a) plural in form and (b) taking a plural verb-form. I would use 'The contents is missing from my copy of 'Burtonnica', and so is the appendix', but that is a different usage.