# What word describes the amount an object is filled to, regarding its capacity?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Given an object that can hold a *capacity* of something, is there a word which describes the current amount it holds towards that capacity?

For example, if an elevator has a capacity of 20 persons, and the current number of occupants is six, the elevator's `<some property of the elevator>` is six?

**Update:** The commentary on @jwpat7's excellent answer made me realize something which hadn't occurred to me: the nature of the container and the things it holds have an impact on the appropriate description. I picked an arbitrary example using people, but the reason I've been seeking this word is to describe discrete (i.e. not something like liquid in a tank) *inanimate* contents.

A better example would be: an egg carton has a capacity of 12 eggs. It currently holds 7. How does one describe the amount currently held: **"The carton's `<this>` is 7 eggs"**?

Comment: quite simply, in English it **depends on the object**. so you'd have to say which items you mean.

Answer (score 8):

*[Occupancy](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/occupancy?region=us&q=occupancy)* seems like the natural word for what you ask, per oxforddictionaries:

> the proportion of accommodations occupied or in use

(*Edit:* The most applicable sense of it in [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/occupancy) is

> The act of occupying, the state of being occupied or the state of being an occupant or tenant

which is rather less satisfactory than the definition shown first.)

Here are some other possibilities: *population, headcount,  crowd size,  census, number, complement, company, fraction.*  A rarely used term is *filledness*. Of all these,  *headcount* perhaps fits best into your example, but others fit with minor rewording:

> The elevator's headcount is six at the moment.
>   Those in the elevator number six at the moment.
>   Those in the elevator are six in number.
>   The elevator party is six in number.
>   There are six persons in the elevator.

*Comment:* As the last of those examples illustrates, one doesn't need a special word (besides *in*) and you may need to revise your question if that being so is unacceptable for some reason.

Comment: [Occupancy](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/occupancy?region=us&q=occupancy) also pertains to the proportion in use, as in the _occupancy_ rate of hotels or office space, so _occupancy_ is the correct answer.

Comment: @Gnawme - Thanks - have updated answer with that link

Comment: Those sound fine as long as the object is being filled with *people*, but not as good for inanimate filling.  It would be strange to talk about the occupancy of a fuel tank.

Comment: @Nate - I agree, one would say "The tank is one-third full" or "The 70-liter tank has 23 liters in it" rather than using odd forms like "The tank's occupancy percent is 33" or "The tank's current literage is 23" as imposed by the original question.

Comment: I think *occupancy* normally only works when the "contents of the container" can reasonably be described as *occupants*. If you're talking about how much liquid is in a glass, or how much rubbish is in a trash-bin, you'd be better off with **fullness**.

Comment: @jwpat7 Thanks for the answer, and the insightful commentary. It didn't occur to me there could be so much variation depending on the nature of the container and its contents. I've updated the question to be more specific about what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a word that would fit in, "The carton's X is 7 eggs." I think the conventional way to say this would be, "The carton contains 7 eggs" or "The carton has 7 eggs in it". If it's something that normally starts out full and is used up -- like an egg carton -- you might say "The carton has 7 eggs remaining" or "... 7 eggs left."

If you're thinking in percentages, it's common to say "The bottle is 35% full" or "The box is half full."

You could, of course, dig out some obscure word or invent a word, but as tchrist notes, it's usually better to use ordinary language even if it is somewhat less concise. I avoid using obscure words or attaching specialized meaning to a word unless I need to use it a lot so it's worth the effort of explaining it.

Answer (score 2):

For inanimate objects, I would suggest *contents*; *the carton's current contents is 4 eggs (out of 6)*

Comment: [Contents is?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50851/the-contents-are-or-the-contents-is)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: A good point. My own feeling is that *contents* is sometimes singular and sometimes plural; nobody would say * "the contents are 2lb, the capacity 3lb." surely? And yes, after consideration I prefer *is* here, though others may differ.

Comment: I've seen 'contents' classed as 'always taking plural concord'; these anomalies (the jury / Government / team / army is or are, but police are) exist. I'd rephrase here. If I may dare quote a TEFL source {[Icaltefl](http://www.icaltefl.com/index.php/nouns/singular-and-plural-nouns.html)}: clothes, contents, earnings, goods, riches, savings, thanks, troops: These nouns take a plural verb. >>

Comment: ... These nouns are all labelled non-count (grammatically; one can count items of clothing, of course), but take plural agreement. 'A _thank you_ is unnecessary' is not very dissimilar to 'Thanks are unnecessary', but both somewhat illogically require different agreement.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: oversimplified to the point of absurdity. *Troops* is plural because the singular is *soldier*: *twenty troops* is not uncommon. *Savings* seems to have different rules either side of the Atlantic, as other questions here attest. *A good* is certainly used in economics. Etc. And if a label read "Contents: 1 pill" would you really say *the contents are one pill*? What about "Contents: 1 ounce"?

Comment: I've already said I'd rephrase. You're choosing to follow logic rather than normal practice.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth; I repeat, I know *nobody* who would say "The contents are 1 pill/ 1 ounce of liquid." Your experience may be different, but that doesn't equal 'normal practice'. Perhaps we should start a new question.

Comment: It's already been answered: [The contents are or the contents is](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50851/the-contents-are-or-the-contents-is). I know nobody who would say 'The contents is one pill'. [OLD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/content_1) states that this usage of _contents_ 'is plural'. // 'Oversimplified to the point of absurdity': I wasn't trying to confuse the issue here by adding in the count-noun usages. And 'Troops is plural because the singular is soldier' is ludicrous.

Answer (score 1):

> “Did you *fill* it?  Sure.  Then how *full* is it now?  I *filled* it up most of the way. It's 80% *full*.  How much does it *hold*? Its *fullness* is at 80% so it *holds* 25% more than it does now.  It *held* nothing when I started.”

I rather like ***full*** and ***hold***, and their related forms. That way you stay within the same close group of related words.

Strong Anglo-Saxon words.  Simple words. Short, sharp words.

Words which everybody knows what mean without having to go dusting off their moldly Latin  dictionary to see how just full tonight’s ***plenilune*** really is.

Comment: Mostly agree, except ... No one says "It's fullness is 80%" More likely "It is 80% full".

Answer (score 1):

**Tally**: (n)a number of objects used as a unit of computation; (v)the act of counting -[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tally)

> If an elevator's current number of occupants is six, the elevator's current tally is six.
>
> An egg carton currently holds 7 eggs. The carton's tally is 7 eggs.
>
> That tallies to just one extra egg if everyone takes one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "population" even for inanimate objects, but it does feel a bit anthropomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

Capacity is the word I would use to describe the utmost something could be filled.

Comment: Hello, David. Please feel welcome. But I have to point out that what you say doesn't answer the question here.

Answer (score 0):

I think "count" fits best.

It's a good question, though, I was going to say "level", until you discretized it.

"This carton's **count** is 7 eggs."

"This elevator has a capacity of 20 persons, its current **count** is six."