# "The contents of the cereal box" — singular or plural?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, nouns, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“The contents are” or “the contents is”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50851/the-contents-are-or-the-contents-is)

Which is correct?

> - The contents of the cereal box **is** distributed among the children.
> - The contents of the cereal box **are** distributed among the children.

"The contents ... are" definitely sounds better, but isn't the word *contents* in this sense singular? Maybe "the contents ... is" is correct, despite the fact that it totally doesn't sound like it is.

Comment: ***contents*** is the plural of ***content***.

Comment: The sentence is correct.

Comment: It should be "The contents are ...".

Comment: I'd use *are*, but can't you just say, "The cereal is distributed..." instead?

Comment: The contents could be toffees!?

Comment: @Kris, in a cereal box?

Comment: @JLG Why not, it doesn't say a ****box of cereal*** so you could be sure. :-) (Well, grammatically they may be the same, but the implication is not.)  We do use a 'shoe box' to store all sorts of things.

Comment: Besides [The contents are or the contents is](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50851), see [Content or contents](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13556),

Comment: @jwpat7 -- done.

Answer (score 4):

Your confusion is understandable as your construction, "The contents", raises a semantic question:

Does a cereal box have "content" (the cereal), or "contents" (the grains of cereal)? I don't think that either of these is definitively right or wrong, but it changes how you write your sentence:

If the cereal box has "contents" (grains of cereal), then:

> The contents of the cereal box are distributed among the children.

If the cereal box has "content" (cereal), then:

> The content of the cereal box is distributed among the children.

In my opinion the second phrasing makes more sense, but that's just an opinion.

Comment: Why do you say that 'the' sounds like the possibility of a singular noun?

Comment: I guess all I mean is, it seems to me that people frequently second guess themselves when they write something like `the (plural noun) are`, and it seems the article is making them second guess whether they should say `the (plural noun) is`, instead of `the (plural noun) are` as the asker indicated.

Comment: I've re-written the answer to be more clear.