# "file content" vs. "file contents"

Tags: meaning

I am aware of [the difference](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13556/content-or-contents) between *content* and *contents* and usually the distinction is clear to me. However I am wondering whether *file content* or *file contents* is more correct. On the one hand, the content of a file is a finite sequence of bytes, hence *contents* would be appropriate. On the other hand, those bytes represent some entity (an image, for example), to which I would refer as the file's *content*. Is this distinction correct, or am I complicating things too much?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are correct.  "Content" (without the S) implies there's some kind of meaning; not just a string of bytes.  If you refer to thefreedictionary.com, the first definition that's NOT shown as synonymous with "contents" is "the substantive or meaningful part"; which in this case is the entity represented by the bytes.

Answer (score 12):

The general usage is **File contents** (when referring to *something contained*)

Google Ngram also shows that *File contents* has an edge over *file content*

[image: Google Ngram]

Comment: Sir, didn't knew about google Ngram thats really awesome thing to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It seems more appropriate to use *file contents*.

For example, PHP programming language has two corresponding functions, named [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

Additionally, note that `file_get_contents()` accepts `offset` and `maxlen` parameters, thus tending to treat the *file contents* as a "sequence of bytes".

Taken from [`file_get_contents()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

> file_get_contents() returns the file in a string, starting at the
>   specified offset up to maxlen bytes

Comment: It's not because a language uses it that it automatically makes it more appropriate. Maybe the dictionary should now spell "referer" with only 3 R's with that kind of logic.